# Why am I getting this output?

Tags: c++, debugging

Alright so I writing Conways Game of Life in C++, and so far I have only created the rule that allows users to create cells if it has 3 neighbors.

Here is the current code: http://tinypaste.com/f59b4463

When I launched the program I entered in the coordinates so that I would have the gameboard depicted in the photo below, and the output wasn't what I expected, it should have made it so that the cell 2,1 would be alive, but in the output it remained dead. I am not sure why it is not working. Any help?

Input & Output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWGc3.png

Comment: oh dear lord. first, write nested for loops instead of writing out all the words individually. make very good use of loops. rewrite, then repost the code.

Comment: Explain more, are you talking about the comments? I am still a beginner.

Comment: also i meant `world` not `word` and nope, not the comments; the code

Comment: it will be much easier to read your code once it's cleaned up

Comment: This must have taken alot of effort to manually type ...

Comment: I can type fast, so it was just getting to concept, and then typing it. I always have troubles with the gameboard, I had the same problem with the gameboard when I made Tic-Tac-Toe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright. It's an algorithmic issue. When you call calculate, it creates extra cells because it's not exactly one generation. It's a mix of two and three - it acts on cells you just created. Get what I'm saying? I explained this on GMail.

Comment: and if i need to clarify, just say so :)

Comment: I understand bro, I am just having troubles thinking how I will make it so that it will know if it was a newly created cell or not. :P

Comment: The rules also do not appear to state on if the newly created cells are counted when checking for neighbors or not...

Comment: They most likely are not, as it's in `generation`s

Comment: Alright, I have fixed the issue, it will be uploaded to Github soon.

Comment: It's not my suggestion that made the problem worse, but the way it is implemented.

Answer (score 2):

Several things to address, and while this is not an answer, it's too big for a comment. Please fix these then I will get back to you...

In `gameboard()` please arrange the code so that it consists of two `for` loops instead of all the `cout`s. Example:

```
int i, j;
for (i = j = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (; j < 10; j++) {
        cout << world[i][j];
    }
}
```

it's much more concise.

Second, in `cells()`, in the second `for` loop, you can use another nested `for` loop.

Third, I would avoid naming normal variables in ALL CAPS since that is generally reserved for preprocessor `#define`s.

K, enjoy cleaning up :)

Comment: Ah for the love of god, most of those things I learned while making the function birth, that is why I used a nested for loop in it and not the others, also, I do not understand your code to print out word.
I really just need help with the main problem, which is why isn't it giving the correct output.

Comment: It will be easier to find the main problem once the code is cleaned up *and* generally arrays start at index `0`.

Comment: http://tinypaste.com/0a6f18ad

I cleaned up a little, and in the birth function, at the end I made it so that if it makes a cell to alive, it makes neighbors = 0, which made it so that if I spammed birth(); in int main(){} it would allow it to function properly, but I would rather want to know why it works when I spammed the birth function so that I can create some other way of doing it.

Comment: @user1048926 please redo gameboard, that is

Comment: I am not sure how, because world, is just the 2D Array where the variables for the alive or dead cells are held. And what your example does is just print out line of un-labeled dashes.

Comment: @user1048926 then the values in each cell appear to be dashes

Comment: But the point in the game of life is to have a gameboard, it has to be a grid, and to have new generations shown on a grid. My problem is that when I run the program, instead of having the spot 2,1 being alive, which is represented as a '+', it is still dead, shown as a dash. Even though it works if I make the cells, 2,1. 2,2,. 1,2. All alive, and run the program, then it makes 1,1 alive like it should.

Comment: right @user1048926 you can have a grid with two nested `for` loops. can someone help explain? it appears i'm not doing too well

Comment: @user1048926 you read what i wrote, right? C++ array indices start at `0`, not `1`

Comment: I see that you are trying your best, and wish that I had 10 rep so we can just chat, but I reread everything you read, and I don't see how what you said would make it turn out into a labeled grid, which is what I need. I still have not solved my problem yet.

Comment: @user1048926 it's not designed to fix the problem yet, but to help me understand your code better, and clean it up

Comment: Yes I know this, and I really want to get it cleaned up since it will become a bad habit. Do you have any other ways to communicate, like a chat, since this isn't exactly ethical.

Comment: @user1048926 you can contact me at tekknolagi@gmail.com if needed.